# ios dynamically created uilabels not returning expected result

Tags: iphone, ios, dynamic, uilabel

I would expect this code to produce the label test 5 times however it produces 5 labels, 4 of which just have 2 dots and the last one has the correct string test.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    int n = 5;
    int yValue = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, yValue, 80, 44)];
        label.text = @"text"; //etc...
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        yValue += 20;
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Height of label - 44. delta between labels - 20, less then 44. Set `yValue+=44` and i think you will see mora than 2 dots. i think dots - top of 't' letters.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height of label - 44. delta between labels - 20, less then 44. Set yValue+=44 and i think you will see mora than 2 dots. i think dots - top of 't' letters.:)

Comment: i would have accepted it right away had it been an answer at first and not just a comment.  Thanks again boss.

Answer (score 0):

Set the font, text color and background color, e.g.

```
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

(code written from memory; not tested. but you get the idea).

When you crate a label like this, you have to set all these things we otherwise take for granted when using Interface Builder.